# Disabled OS X Server still appear on localhost

Tags: macos, osx-server

Before when I entered `localhost` into the browser there was my localhost from `MAMP`, basically directory for my web repositories. Recently I installed **OS X Server**, and now when I enter `localhost` into the browser there is:

[image]

**How to disable OS X Server and bring back to my MAMP localhost?**

In OS X Server everything is turned off:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to turn of the website(*) in the OS X Server app? *I'm not sure if website is the correct name

Comment: turn on or off?

Comment: Off. Can't change my first comment

Comment: Everything is turned off... what else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off the `Webserver` from OS X Server's `Server Admin`. In fact, if you are not planning to use it, I would recommend shutting down all the services from `Server Admin`

Comment: But everything is turned off in OS X Server.

Comment: Oh, then check for if any services are still on under `System Preferences`->`Sharing` and disable them.

Comment: Yes, it helped:) there was turned on Remote Login.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually **two** things you could do.

**Option 1**
You can edit your host file and so localhost won't be used by OS X server anymore. How to edit your host file is explained in [this link.](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/edit-hosts-file-mac-os-x/)

**Option 2**
I prefer this option, which is available in *MAMP PRO*. I'm not sure if it is available in the free version of *MAMP*.

When you open MAMP, click on the host tab. You will now see this screen:
[image: Screenshot of MAMP PRO - Hosts]
You can than change the server name and start/restart you services to apply the changes.
In the screenshot above, I can access my website

> http://localhost/ 
>   and
>   http://website/

I hope this will solve your problem.